# Color doesn't change on css/jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this jquery code :

```
var regexparam="([^a-zA-Z ])";                                                
if(thisValue.match(regexparam))                                    
{                                                                                                                                        
     $(parentId).children('span').addClass('red').html('&#10005;  Firstname cannot contain numbers or symbols.');                                     
}
else if($.trim(thisValue)=="")                                    
{
    $(parentId).children('span').addClass('red').html('&#10005;   Firstname cannot be empty.');                                        
}
else
{
    $(parentId).children('span').addClass('green').html('&#10004;   So you\'re '+ thisValue+'.');                                
}
```

The 'red' class is being rendered when the user inputs wrong information...
While the 'green' class doesn't apply and revert back to it's default color.

I checked on the firebug and the class is being rendered and I can see that both green and red class is being applied to the element.

Here's my css:

```
.red{color:red;};
.green{color:green;};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css has snytax errors, remove the `;` after each group

```
.red{color:red;}
.green{color:green;}
```

Comment: Urggggggggh yeah syntax problem jeeez

Answer (score 0):

Just use `toggleClass()` in spite of `addClass()`.

Because probably whats happening is that the previous values are not getting overridden .

And you can also try using

```
.red{color:red !important;}
.green{color:green !important ;}
```

but do use this trick with caution

Answer (score 0):

You can do `.removeClass('red').removeClass('green').addClass('<requiredOne>')`